# Merging two lists of dictionaries with mostly dissimilar keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
dl1 = [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.06081700'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00405000'}]
dl2 = [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'makerCommission': '0.001', 'takerCommission': '0.001'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'makerCommission': '0', 'takerCommission': '0.001'}]
```

I would like to merge them together on `symbol` like so:

```
{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.06081700', 'makerCommission': '0.001', 'takerCommission': '0.001'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00405000', 'makerCommission': '0', 'takerCommission': '0.001'}
```

I've read answers here about various methods to do things similar to this, which include `defaultdict()`, list comprehension, pandas, `extend()`, and loops but I haven't found any answers that describe how to do exactly this, where each dictionary across both lists has dissimilar keys and values, other than the one I want to merge on.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: The lists are already ordered correctly with regard to the "symbol"?

Comment: If you mean that for `symbol` in `dl1` and `dl2` are always in the same position, relative to one another in their respective lists, then I don't know.  I didn't know that was important; my assumption was that whatever method was used would't care about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty easy with pandas. Just convert your dict to a dataframe and merge then convert back to a dict.

```
pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(dl1), pd.DataFrame(dl2), on='symbol').to_dict(orient='records')

[{'symbol': 'ETHBTC',
  'price': '0.06081700',
  'makerCommission': '0.001',
  'takerCommission': '0.001'},
 {'symbol': 'LTCBTC',
  'price': '0.00405000',
  'makerCommission': '0',
  'takerCommission': '0.001'}]
```

Comment: Pandas looks interesting, but I was curious about whether that would be considered that  un-pythonic?  (disclosure:  I don't know what is and what isn't pythonic, generally speaking, but I have seen other discussions where the argument is for or against pythonic behaviour so I figure some approaches are and aren't?)

Comment: @Jason it is not "un-pythonic" to use pandas I just noticed that you mentioned pandas in your question (after all a pandas DataFrame is essentially just a dictionary). However, if you are looking to use pure python without additional packages I would recommend schwobaseggl's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and dict unpacking:

```
dl_merge = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(dl1, dl2)]
```

If the lists are not ordered yet, you would have to find the matching element from the second list, preferrably with constant lookup time:

```
dl2_aux = {d["symbol"]: d for d in dl2}  # assumes each symbol occurs only once

dl_merge = [{**d1, **dl2_aux.get(d1["symbol"], {})} for d1 in dl1]
```